# Why might the following hang the program?

Tags: c++

Now that I've got SmartPointers, I decided to try DumbPointers, which do the terribly difficult job of calling "delete" in a destructor. Deciding to continue my tests of storing arrays in SmartPointer, using a DumbPointer, I recalled a previous error and tried this:

```
DumbPointer<char> dumbPointer = "Hello World\0";
```

For undefined reasons of "Perhaps that's not a pointer or proper pointer?", it causes the program to hang. Naturally, I'd like to know why, with an eye toward solving said problem. I will now provide the terribly complex DumbPointer code (maybe I should go to sleep) below: (Let me re-assure you: The destructor is called)

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"

template <typename T> class DumbPointer
{
private:
T* myPtr;

public:
T* Value() { return myPtr; }

DumbPointer(const DumbPointer<T>& a)
 { throw new "No assignments between DumbPointer."; }
DumbPointer(T* ptr) { myPtr = ptr; }
DumbPointer(T value) { myPtr = &value; }
~DumbPointer() { delete myPtr; }


operator T*() { return myPtr; }
T* operator ->() { return myPtr; }
};
```

Comment: Off topic from your actual question, but here's a tip. Replace

`DumbPointer(const DumbPointer<T>& a)
 { throw new "No assignments between DumbPointer."; }`

with

`private:
DumbPointer(const DumbPointer<T>& a); //DumbPointers may not be copied`

(If you declare a method, but don't define it (don't give it a body), your code will compile if you don't try to use that method, but the compile will fail if you do try to use it.)

Basically, changing your "no copy" restriction to a compile-time error, rather than a run-time error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must only `delete` pointers that you allocated with `new`. You pass a string constant to your DumbPointer, which has static allocation.

Comment: Not automatic, but in static storage, but `delete`ing it is UB anyway.

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't sure of the calling conventions of string literals, although it makes sense for them not to use new. Thanks.

Comment: @Sharptooth: I have no idea what you just said, sorry.

Comment: @Narf the Mouse: UB is "undefined behavior" which in short is "something very very bad" - including (but not limited to) hanging or crashing your program.

Comment: @NarftheMouse: UB is undefined behavior. This means that the standard doesn't define what should be done in this case. If someone tells you something is UB that means that you are not certain that a piece of code will work correctly. Thus, it is a bad idea to use code that contains UB.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Frederik's comment, I would just add that there's absolutely no reason to assign a string constant to a smart pointer.

Since there's absolutely nothing to delete here, just assign it to a plain old `char*` pointer. Again, there's nothing that needs deleting or cleaning up.

Comment: After I read his comment, that's the general line of thought I followed.